# How to change the default no of records displayed on OpenERP

Tags: odoo

By default, OpenERP displays 20 records when retrieving data. Is there any way I can change the default no of records to something else? I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the limit of the items displayed in a view, you have to edit the Window Action attached to it.

Go to `Settings > Technical > Actions > Window Actions` (Odoo v10).
Select the action you want to change, edit and change the field `Limit`, for the number of records you want to display.

Alternately, with `Developer Mode` activated, open the view. Open `Developer Tools (the bug icon) > Edit Action` and change field `Limit`.

Comment: I didn't found in openerp 5.0.16 , is there an other way to resolve that ? thank you

Comment: I can found this in openerp 6.1. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

To change the default number of records to display in a tree view, When you define the action
add  `<field name="limit">your_record_limit</field>`
For example, in sale order the default number of record is 80, we can change it to 150 by adding `<field name="limit">150</field>` to the ir.action.act_window

```
<record id="action_order_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Sales Orders</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="limit">150</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form,calendar,graph</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_sales_order_filter"/>
</record>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I have a chart of accounts that I want to display all at once instead if in 20s. After adding  a limit, it was still displaying 20 records for me

Comment: An image of what now? Of the accounts list or the xml?

Comment: hey, got toAdministration > Customization > Low level Objects >window Actions
search for Accounts, there you can see a field limit. provide your limit there

Comment: How to display unlimited record in the tree view, I tried <field name="limit">0</field>, but it doesn't work